# Toggling a blog post loop excerpts with jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, toggle, blogs, effect

I'd like to reveal only post titles on my blog posts loop, and when the title is clicked -- the excerpt will appear below.

So far I got this:

```
$("#postTitle").click(function () {
$("#postExcerpt").toggle();
```

Which works one the first result only.

This, however:

```
$("#postTitle").click(function () {
$("#postExcerpt").next().toggle();
```

Doesn't work at all, and I can't figure out why.

My loop looks like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="block">
    <p id="postTitle"><a href="#">Post Title</a></p>
    <p id="postExcerpt" style="display:none;">Post Excerpt</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post a larger example of "loop", with more than one entry. Do all of them have identical ids?

Comment: The posts gather up in this form. You can just copy paste it in your mind.

Yes, they all have the same IDs. Is there any other way to toggle them?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, many of them, but you should know that ids must be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#postTitle a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('#postTitle').siblings('#postExcerpt').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Demo here: http://jquery.nodnod.net/cases/702/run

Of course, you should never reuse HTML IDs. You should use classes.

Comment: BTW: How hard it is to make this code act like Accordion? I mean, opening one element while closing the rest?